# c# Access to path denied?

Tags: c#, access-denied, temporary-directory

I'm having trouble with an error. I have searched the web but havent found an answer that made sense to me. I'm basically trying to create a temporary text file, and write to it. Here it the code concerning the error:

```
using ( StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(File.Create(GetTemporaryDirectory())))
```

and the getTemporaryDirectory method:

```
 public string GetTemporaryDirectory() {
        string tempDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());
        string tempFile = Path.ChangeExtension(tempDirectory, ".txt");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFile);
        return tempFile;
    }
```

and last but not least the error:

> dir = C:\Users\Jack Givens\AppData\Local\Temp\5ftxwy31.txt
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Users\Jack Givens\AppData\Local\Temp\0lpe1k5t.txt' is denied.

If anyone can tell me what is wrong with my code and what i need to do to fix it, I will appreciate it. side note: sorry for crappy code, i'm kinda a beginner :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `CreateDirectory` on your filename so now a folder exists in the path that `File.Create` is attempting to call. Just simply remove the `Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFile);` line (it is not needed as the folder is guaranteed to exist) and your code should work.

Comment: In addition to what Scott wrote, you should change all the places where you wrote "directory" in the method to say "file" instead. It really has little to do with directories, so you don't want to leave misleading method and variable names there.

Comment: Ah i did not realize that i was creating two of the same file. thanks so much!

Comment: @Jack You where not creating two of the same file, you where creating a directory with the name of the file you wanted to create before you tried to create a file.

Answer (score 5):

```
 Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFile);
```

You have just created a directory, the name of which ends in "*.txt".

Then you attempt to create a file with the exact same path.  But that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a directory, not a file. You can't open a directory as a file.